# Store specific fields of a file as the values in an associative array bash

Tags: bash, shell, associative-array

There is a file that looks something like this:

```
f1.1 f2.1 f3.1 f4.1
f1.2 f2.2 f3.2 f4.2
f1.3 f2.3 f3.3 f4.3
```

Then I use column 1 as the key in an associative array:

```
declare -A arr=(); while read -r a b; do arr["$a"]="$b"; done <file
```

Result of printing the keys and values out:

```
for K in "${!arr[@]}"; do
    echo $K --- ${arr[$K]}
done

f1.1 --- f2.1 f3.1 f4.1
f1.2 --- f2.2 f3.2 f4.2
f1.3 --- f2.3 f3.3 f4.3
```

What if I only want column 2 and 3 to be stored as values? Such that the above command gives:

```
f1.1 --- f2.1 f3.1
f1.2 --- f2.2 f3.2
f1.3 --- f2.3 f3.3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on what your needs are, but i would do some [awk](http://linux.die.net/man/1/awk) magic:

```
# will print:
# f1.1 --- f2.1 f3.1
# f1.2 --- f2.2 f3.2
# ...
awk '{print $1" --- "$2" "$3}' file
```

You can also use awk mixed with your bash:

```
declare -A arr=(); 
while read -r a b; do 
  rr["$a"]="$(echo $b | awk '{print $1" "$2}')" 
done < file
```

Comment: I meant the result of printing the keys/values from the associative array gives "col1 --- col2 col3" rather than just directly printing from the file? Or in other words the associative array only stores "col2 col3" as the value instead of "col2 col3 col4" hope that makes sense

Comment: `arr["$a"]="$(echo $b|awk '{print $1" "$2}')"` :D ?